# C# or VB in Blogengine.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iframe, blogengine.net

I have several page on my Blogengine.net site that requires a C# or vb code behind. I have made the pages and simply display them in an iFrame on the blogengine page.

Now I have found that Google does not index the iFrame content so I want to do away with the iFrames.

How can I create a page in BlogEngine.net that uses vb or c# code also?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create custom page from admin panel.

Content --> Pages --> New

Create your new page.

Then click the name of the page which you created.

Add your codes as source code also your stylesheet as `<style> </style>` in the bottom of the source code.

Try to use ID for elements.

I am using for my content list in my blog. http://momoware.co/